# get the toplevel folder name used by readpst -r?

Tags: directory, email, file-format

I've come across the following minor problem trying to automate my use of [readpst](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/index.html):

```
readpst -w /some/dir/ -r mailtst.pst
```

I can't predict the name of the top-level dir without some prior knowledge about the .pst.

Here I had known that it will be "mailtst" (from previous runs), and renamed the .pst file accordingly, so that this information is obvious.

The output of readpst -r is not enough, because it only mentions it in one line:

```
       "mailtst" - 28 items done, 0 items skipped.
```

without any indications that it is the top-level folder. And there are no lines of the form:

```
Processing Folder "Deletions"
```

for the top-level one.

How can I get the top-level dir from the .pst file?

(And: Is it true that there will always be only one top-level dir with arbitrary unpredictable name? If yes, then its name bears no meaning to any automation tools and should be auto-detected, as I try to do. If no, it should be a parameter. If it is meaningless, perhaps there should be a variant of the `readpst -o` which uses the given directory as the top-level, not the internal unpredictable one.)